# open source/free MPMediaPicker replacement?

Tags: iphone, ios

i'm looking to rebuild the MPMediaPicker from scratch (it's using my own song/artist data).
Does anyone know of an open source and free replacement for this? I'd really like to avoid creating all those views/etc

I've found PSMediaPicker, but it's $100.

I could have sworn I came across one - but I'm unable to find it anywhere.

Comment: The first place I looked is [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640805/open-source-ios-components-reusable-views-controllers-buttons-table-cells-e), by the way. Great repository for links to iOS components.

Comment: sweet thread. I book-marked that puppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating one for your own song/artist data then I would highly recommend just creating your own. If it is for music then it wouldn't really be much more than a modal view with some UITableViews in it, and since you know how the data is organized it shouldn't take long to get it up and running.

Bottom line - t will probably take you longer to find and integrate a suitable replacement than it would to just roll your own.